# swing - how to switch JPanel using button

Tags: java, swing, button, jpanel, switch-statement

Hi guys I'm planning to create login panel. In that panel should be user JLabel, password JLabel, user JTextField, password JTextField, and JButon. I would like to use that button to switch to new JPanel. I've read the best way is CardLayout and I'm trying to modify that code:

```
//Where the GUI is assembled:
//Put the JComboBox in a JPanel to get a nicer look.
JPanel comboBoxPane = new JPanel(); //use FlowLayout
String comboBoxItems[] = { BUTTONPANEL, TEXTPANEL };
JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(comboBoxItems);
cb.setEditable(false);
cb.addItemListener(this);
comboBoxPane.add(cb);
...
pane.add(comboBoxPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
pane.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
...

//Method came from the ItemListener class implementation,
//contains functionality to process the combo box item selecting
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
    cl.show(cards, (String)evt.getItem());
}
```

I'm trying to modify that part of code

```
JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(comboBoxItems);
cb.setEditable(false);
cb.addItemListener(this);
comboBoxPane.add(cb);
pane.add(comboBoxPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
pane.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

and change it in to:

```
JButton loginButton = new JButton();
loginButton.addItemListener(this);
comboBoxPane.add(loginButton);
pane.add(loginButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
pane.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I can't use:

```
JButton loginButton = new JButton(comboBoxItems);
```

because compiler return error: The constructor JButton(String[]) is undefined

is any one can help me with my problem. I'm newbie in Java programming

Comment: If that is a problem, you better start with some basic Java tutorials. Just copying code from the internet and trying to make some modifications without understanding what it does will just lead you from one problem to another

Comment: Yes I understand your point, I'm learning Java basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JButton` does not have a constructor which takes a `String` array. It is sufficient to call:

```
JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
```

See: [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)